# In modular arithmetic, why is (x mod n)^y mod n == x^y mod n?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why is `(x mod n)^y mod n == x^y mod n`? It seems to me like there is a property in modular arithmetic that explains why, does anyone have a simple way of explaining it?

Comment: Hint:  just show that $(x+n)^y\equiv x^y\pmod n$.  The binomial theorem might help.

Comment: It's possible that your comment made me understand it. Will let it bake a bit, and see if I connected the dots.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$g^{k_1}=nq_1+r$$therefore$$(g^{k1}\mod n)^{k2} \mod n=r^{k_2}\mod n$$Furthermore:$$(g^{k_1})^{k_2}\mod n=(nq+r)^{k_2}\mod n=nq_2+r^{k_2}\mod n=r^{k_2}\mod n$$therefore$$(g^{k1}\mod n)^{k2} \mod n=(g^{k_1})^{k_2}\mod n$$